# What's the number next to the tag?

Tags: support, tags

There is a number next to a tag. What does it represent? I can't make any sense of the numbers. [image: Number]

Comment: Not quite sure what "number" you are referring to. Is there any chance you could include a screenshot?

Comment: The highlighted numbers. what are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is your total score for each tag. You accumulate them from writing answers to questions with those tags. The score of each post is the number of upvotes minus downvotes.

Comment: Just to make it a little clearer: question upvotes do not contribute to your score in a tag, only answer upvotes do.